# Formatic UI DatePicker is out of screen

Tags: javascript, jquery, html, css, semantic-ui

Pretty new here, so sorry if the solutions are a bit "obvious":)
I'm using a datepicker/calendar of "formatic UI", dealing with two issues:

1. When clicking the input, the pop-up picker is out off screen. I've tried to fix it with css positions (also a bit js) but really stack how to do it only to the pop up picker and not to the input. Also, my language is Hebrew so there might be a problem regarding to rtl issues (I've tried a rtl CDN, still was not that helpful=/)
2. This picker is used to filter my data. The problem is when a user click on the popup picker, the picker is changed, but only when clicking again the input, data is filtered. Filtering function supposed to be on "keyup, click, change" but still, not working when value is changed. (for other inputs- when value is changed - it indeed working. Only this picker has an issue)

my code:

```js
$(document).ready(function () {
    $('#start_date_picker,#end_date_picker').on("keyup click change", filterAll);
}); 

 
  var today = new Date();
$('#rangestart').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  endCalendar: $('#rangeend'),
 text: {
      days: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ש'],
      months: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני', 'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'נובמבר', 'דצמבר'],
      monthsShort: ['ינ', 'פב', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יונ', 'יול', 'אוג', 'ספט', 'אוק', 'נוב', 'דצמ'],
      today: 'היום',
      now: 'כעת'
    },
  minDate: new Date(today.getFullYear(), today.getMonth(), today.getDate() ),
    monthFirst: false,
 formatter: {
      date: function (date, settings) {
        if (!date) return '';
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
  var year= date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
        return day + '.' + month +  '.' + year;
      }
    } 
});
$('#rangeend').calendar({
  type: 'date',
  startCalendar: $('#rangestart'),
 text: {
      days: ['א', 'ב', 'ג', 'ד', 'ה', 'ו', 'ש'],
      months: ['ינואר', 'פברואר', 'מרץ', 'אפריל', 'מאי', 'יוני', 'יולי', 'אוגוסט', 'ספטמבר', 'אוקטובר', 'נובמבר', 'דצמבר'],
      monthsShort: ['ינ', 'פב', 'מרץ', 'אפר', 'מאי', 'יונ', 'יול', 'אוג', 'ספט', 'אוק', 'נוב', 'דצמ'],
      today: 'היום',
      now: 'כעת'
    },
    monthFirst: false,
  formatter: {
      date: function (date, settings) {
        if (!date) return '';
        var day = date.getDate();
        var month = date.getMonth() + 1;
    var year= date.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
        return day + '.' + month +  '.' + year;
      }
    }
});
 
 var start_date_picker = document.getElementById('start_date_picker');
 var end_date_picker = document.getElementById('end_date_picker');
 var month_picker_start = today.getMonth()+1;
 var year_picker_start= today.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);
 
    var week_from_today = new Date();
      week_from_today.setDate(week_from_today.getDate() +  7);
 var month_week_from_today = week_from_today.getMonth()+1;
 var year_from_today= week_from_today.getFullYear().toString().substr(-2);

 
 if(start_date_picker) {start_date_picker.value = today.getDate()+ "." + month_picker_start+ "." + year_from_today;}
 if(end_date_picker) {end_date_picker.value = week_from_today.getDate()+ "." +month_week_from_today + "." + year_from_today;}
```

```html
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.css">
<script src="https://cdn.jsdelivr.net/npm/semantic-ui@2.4.2/dist/semantic.min.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript" src="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-calendar/0.0.8/calendar.min.js"></script>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="https://cdnjs.cloudflare.com/ajax/libs/semantic-ui-calendar/0.0.8/calendar.min.css" />

<i class="ui calendar" id="rangestart">
          <div class="ui transparent input right icon">
            <i class="calendar alternate outline icon grey icon"></i>
            <input type="text" id="start_date_picker" style="text-align:right;">
          </div>
  </i>
 -
       <i class="ui calendar" id="rangeend">
          <div class="ui transparent input right icon">
            <input type="text" id="end_date_picker"  style="text-align:right;">
          </div>
        </i>
```